# Two cloned SwiftUI Views behaving differently

Tags: swiftui

I am using Xcode 13.4.1.  I have two NavigationViews, both called from the same List of menu items (Buttons).  The code of the two Views are identical, other than that they reference a different CoreData entity and have independent ViewModels.  The first View correctly displays two Buttons and works like a dream over the Qualifier data.  The second View refuses to display the "plus.circle" Button and seems to ignore it.  I have compared the code multiple times and cannot see any reason for the different behaviour.  The working code below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct QualifiersMainView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var returnToMain
    @EnvironmentObject var qualifierVM: QualifierViewModel
    @FetchRequest(entity: QQEntity.entity(),
                  sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "qName", ascending: true)],
                  animation: .default) private var listOfQualifiers: FetchedResults<QQEntity>

    @State private var addView = false
    @State private var isEdit = false
    @State private var totalQualifiers: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Total Qualifiers: \(totalQualifiers)")
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .bold()
                ForEach(listOfQualifiers) { qualifier in                    QualifierListCell(qualifierItem: qualifier, addView: false)
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $addView) {
                    QualifierAddView(addView: $addView, isEdit: $isEdit)
                        .onAppear {
                            countQualifiers()
                        }
                }
                .toolbar {
                    Button(action: {
                        qualifierVM.qualifierName = ""
                        qualifierVM.qualifierItem = nil
                        addView.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Label("Add Qualifier", systemImage: "plus.circle")
                    })
                }
                .navigationTitle("Qualifiers")
                .onAppear {
                    countQualifiers()
                }
            }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button(action: {
                            returnToMain.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .font(.headline)
                                .padding(20)
                        })
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    
    func countQualifiers() {
        totalQualifiers = listOfQualifiers.count
    }
}
```

The errant code below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContactsMainView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var returnToMain
    @EnvironmentObject var contactVM: ContactViewModel
    @FetchRequest(entity: ContactEntity.entity(),
                  sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "contactLastName", ascending: true)],
                  animation: .default) private var listOfContacts: FetchedResults<ContactEntity>

    @State private var addView = false
    @State private var isEdit = false
    @State private var totalContacts: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Total Contacts: \(totalContacts)")
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .bold()
                ForEach(listOfContacts) { contact in                    ContactListCell(contactItem: contact, addView: false)
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $addView) {
                    ContactAddView(addView: $addView, isEdit: $isEdit)
                        .onAppear {
                            countContacts()
                        }
                }
                .toolbar {
                    Button(action: {
                        contactVM.contactFirstName = ""
                        contactVM.contactLastName = ""
                        contactVM.contactItem = nil
                        addView.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Label("Add Contact", systemImage: "plus.circle")
                    })
                }
                .navigationTitle("Contacts")
                .onAppear {
                    countContacts()
                }
            }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button(action: {
                            returnToMain.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .font(.headline)
                                .padding(20)
                        })
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    
    func countContacts() {
        totalContacts = listOfContacts.count
    }
}
```

Now added the 3x classes code:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataManager: ObservableObject {
    
    let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer
    static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    
    var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    
    @Published var listOfQualifiers: [QQEntity] = []
    @Published var listofContacts: [ContactEntity] = []
    @Published var listOfClients: [ClientEntity] = []
    @Published var listOfOpportunities: [OpportunityEntity] = []
    @Published var selectedClient: [ClientEntity] = []
    
    init() {
        persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "B2BDataModel")
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Error loading Core Data. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Successfully loaded Core Data...")
            }
        }
    }
    func getAllQualifiers() -> [QQEntity] {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<QQEntity> = QQEntity.fetchRequest()
        do {
        return try viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            return []
        }
    }
    
    func getAllClients() -> [ClientEntity] {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<ClientEntity> = ClientEntity.fetchRequest()
        do {
        return try viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            return []
        }
    }
    
    func getAllContacts() -> [ContactEntity] {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<ContactEntity> = ContactEntity.fetchRequest()
        do {
        return try viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            return []
        }
    }
    
    func getAllOpportunities() -> [OpportunityEntity] {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<OpportunityEntity> = OpportunityEntity.fetchRequest()
        do {
        return try viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            return []
        }
    }
    
    func getAllFlags() -> [FlagEntity] {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<FlagEntity> = FlagEntity.fetchRequest()
        do {
        return try viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import CoreData

class QualifierViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var qualifierNumber: Int16 = 0
    @Published var qualifierName = ""
    @Published var qualifierNarrative = ""
    @Published var qualifierExplanation = ""
    @Published var qualifierItem: QQEntity!
    
    func addQualifier(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        if qualifierItem == nil {
        let qualifier = QQEntity(context: context)
        qualifier.qNumber = qualifierNumber
        qualifier.qName = qualifierName
        qualifier.qNarrative = qualifierNarrative
        qualifier.qExplanation = qualifierExplanation
        }
        else {
            qualifierItem.qNumber = qualifierNumber
            qualifierItem.qName = qualifierName
            qualifierItem.qNarrative = qualifierNarrative
            qualifierItem.qExplanation = qualifierExplanation
        }
        save(context: context)
        qualifierNumber = 0
        qualifierName = ""
        qualifierNarrative = ""
        qualifierExplanation = ""
    }
    
    func editQualifier(qualifier: QQEntity) {
        qualifierItem = qualifier
    }
    
    func delete(qualifier: QQEntity, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        context.delete(qualifier)
        save(context: context)
    }
    
    func save(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error saving: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import CoreData

class ContactViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var contactFirstName = ""
    @Published var contactLastName = ""
    @Published var contactCellNumber = ""
    @Published var contactComments = ""
    @Published var contactEmail = ""
    @Published var contactCreated: Date = Date()
    @Published var contactUpdated: Date = Date()
    @Published var contactChampion = false
    @Published var contactItem: ContactEntity!
    
    func addContact(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        if contactItem == nil {
        let contact = ContactEntity(context: context)
        contact.contactFirstName = contactFirstName
        contact.contactLastName = contactLastName
        contact.contactCellNumber = contactCellNumber
        contact.contactComments = contactComments
        contact.contactEmail = contactEmail
        contact.contactCreated = contactCreated
        contact.contactUpdated = contactUpdated
        contact.contactChampion = contactChampion
        }
        else {
            contactItem.contactFirstName = contactFirstName
            contactItem.contactLastName = contactLastName
            contactItem.contactCellNumber = contactCellNumber
            contactItem.contactComments = contactComments
            contactItem.contactEmail = contactEmail
            contactItem.contactCreated = contactCreated
            contactItem.contactUpdated = contactUpdated
            contactItem.contactChampion = contactChampion
        }
        save(context: context)
        contactFirstName = ""
        contactLastName = ""
        contactCellNumber = ""
        contactComments = ""
        contactEmail = ""
        contactCreated = Date()
        contactUpdated = Date()
        contactChampion = false
        
    }
    
    func editContact(contact: ContactEntity) {
        contactItem = contact
    }
    
    func delete(contact: ContactEntity, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        context.delete(contact)
        save(context: context)
    }
    
    func save(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error saving: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should be reusing the view instead of creating two duplicates

also without the unincluded classes its hard to tell what the issue is

Comment: I have added the three class files.  A bit concerned about my use of Combine - I don't fully understand it, yet.  Also, I have tried to move the 'Add Button' inside the other toolbar and wrapped both Buttons in an HStack - the + now displays, but doesn't invoke the .sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!  I moved the Add Contact Button and the sheet into the ToolbarItem closure.  It doesn't however explain why the original code is working.  I suspect an overuse of NavigationView may be the culprit.